# Google Sheets Count if unique & contains

Tags: filter, count, google-sheets, unique, countif

I'm trying to figure out how I can count through order numbers in a column which is shared with other data.

I only want to count if the order number is unique, I was trying to use the end suffix of all order numbers as criteria but can't seem to be able to get it identify two types of criteria.

All I need it to return is the total amount of orders in the column, ignore the total qtys it shares underneath in the same column and only return the unique values.

I tried: =countif('sheet'!A1:A, unique("*suffix"))

Comment: Maybe you could add a little example of the data stored in your column A, and the expected output for the formula. I don't understand what "shared with other data" means, or what are you trying to achieve with `unique("*suffix")`... Do you want to count the number of cells in a column, whose value ends in the string `"suffix"`?

Comment: Regarding the shared data, I have 2 different types of data in the same column, and yes I want to only count the rows that finish with the "suffix", all my order numbers end with the same 3 initials, so I thought if I could somehow get it to only count strings that end with that suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth trying:

```
=unique(filter(A:A,right(A:A,6)="suffix"))
```

though like @AJPerez, I'm not sure what is required, from what.